# What is the use of SPHttpUtility.NoEncode method?

Tags: sharepoint, internals

Does anybody know what is the usefulness of the SPHttpUtility.NoEncode method? It seems like it takes a string as parameters and returns it without any modification.

Is there a case where you can use this and I'm missing it?

Answer (score 0):

The data in sharepoint that is markup content has to be encoded so that it can be passed around in xml without it breaking.

for example & lt;a / & gt; instead of "< a/ >" (without the spaces)

Therefore if you want to ouput the rendered  instead of >a /< you use the NoEncode function to convert it to valid xml.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Brian I know that this is what the documentation says this method does but when testing it doesn't do anything.